# Как просмотреть массив элементов?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Столкнулся с необходимостью просмотреть содержания массива в режиме отладки поэлементно, пока не нашёл такой возможности в VS2010, кто сталкивался, подскажите как?

Comment: у тебя наверно демоверсия...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался, когда вызываешь QuikWatch, в Expression находится переменная, например ptr, после имени переменной ставится запятая и количество элементов для просмотра - ptr,100
Вуаля и всё показывает!

Answer (score 1):

В режиме дебага выбрать переменную массива и нажать `quickwatch`.

Comment: quickwatch - где он находится!?

Comment: правой кнопкой мыши по переменной...

Comment: пытаюсь посмотреть на указатель, пишет ошибку - overloaded operator not found

Comment: другим словом есть указатель который куда то смотрит, как посмотреть дамп памяти!?

Comment: В окне watch'ей нужно вписать наименование указателя и модификатор. Их список можно где-то в справке студии найти, но в целом они аналогичны строчкам формата ф-ций семейства printf

Answer (score 0):

1) Запустить отладку.
2) "Shift + F9" или вручную: правой кнопкой мыши по месту, где пишется код, и выбрать "Быстрая проверка..." (или "QuikWatch").
3) Если массив создавался так:

```
int n;
std::cin >> n;
int* M = new int[n];
```

То в "Выражении" (или "Expression") написать без кавычек: "M, 8"
(так будут видны первые 8 элементов массива M).
4) Нажать "Добавить контрольное значение"
5) Снизу, где "Видимые", "Локальные", "Контрольные значения 1", выбрать "Контрольные значения 1". Готово!